# Show that the set is a singleton

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be convex, differential function. Consider the set $$X=\left\{x\in \underset{x}{\text{argmin}} f(x):\; \|x\|\leq \|y\|,\;\forall y\in \underset{x}{\text{argmin}} f(x)\right\}$$ Prove that this set is a singleton. What I can establish so far is that $\forall x,x'\in X,x\ne x',\;f(x)=f(x')=f(\alpha x+ (1-\alpha)x'),\forall \alpha\in(0,1)$ due to convexity and $\|x\|=\|x'\|=\|\alpha x + (1-\alpha)x'\|$ due to triangle inequality. But I don't see how to get that $x=x'$ from here.

Comment: I don't know the meaning of *argmin*, and there is a chance that I am not only one.

Comment: Is $\Vert \cdot\Vert$ the standard Euclidean norm?

Comment: It's $x$ s.t. $f(x)$ is minimal.

Comment: Yes, $\|.\|$ is a standard Euclidean norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand $\|\alpha x + (1-\alpha)x'\|^2$ and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the inner product term. The equality happens only when $x$ and $x'$ are parallel...